# Rails - EmailVeracity - setting the domain_check and timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using EmailVeracity today as follows:

```
email = EmailVeracity::Address.new(params[:user][:email])
```

I would like to know how to disable the domain_check and/or lower the timeout. I tried:

```
email = EmailVeracity::Address.new(params[:user][:email], :domain_check => false, :timeout => 5, :message => "is not valid")
```

But get an ArgumentError, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, look here: https://github.com/heycarsten/email-veracity/blob/master/lib/email_veracity/config.rb

So (this is untested), something like

```
EmailVeracity::Config[:skip_lookup] = true
```

should be what you're looking for.